# When to unsubscribe a subscription

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I have a question regarding how to unsubscribe an observable. I have two codes and I'm not really sure about which one is better.

Example 1 -> Unsubscribe the subscriber once the stream has finished:

```
Subscriber<String> subscriber = new Subscriber<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            progressdialog.dissmiss();
            unsubscribe();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            progressdialog.dissmiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(String s) {
            // do something with data
        }
    }
```

Example 2 -> Unsubscribe the subscription once the activity is destroyed:

```
private void test(){
    Subscriber<String> subscriber = new Subscriber<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            progressdialog.dissmiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            progressdialog.dissmiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(String s) {
            // do something with data
        }
    };

    subscription = BackendRequest.login(loginRequest)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(subscriber);

    compositeSubscription.add(subscription);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

I have to mention that my observables only will emit once, the activity should not wait for more calls from the Observable.

Which one is better?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm having troubles getting my code (with pull to refresh) to refresh a second time when using a pull to refresh listener. I have verified that my pull to refresh is working correctly but the second set of "observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(subscriber)" is not working, only the first. Any ideas?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the two options the second one is better.

In your first example you're `unsubscribing` in the `onComplete()` method which is not needed. If you reach the `onComplete()` of a Subscription you don't have the responsibility of unsubscribing from it anymore.

Your second example is the correct one. The idea behind the `CompositeSubscription` is that you can add multiple `Subscriptions` to it and then clean up (`unsubscribe`) at once. In other words this just saves you from the need of keeping a list of `Subscriptions` that you need to unsubscribe from.

One tricky part using `CompositeSubscription` is that if you once `unsubscribe` it, you can **NOT** use it again. You can check the documentation for the [compositeSubscription.add()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subscriptions/CompositeSubscription.html#add(rx.Subscription)) method for details why. In short - it will directly unsubscribe the Subscription you're trying to add. That's been a deliberate decision (you can read more about it [HERE](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/2959)).

Coming back to your example, calling `unsubscribe()` in `onDestroy()` of the Activity is fine and will save you from memory leaks. Regarding your comment that problems occur when you call your `test()` method multiple times - I'd say your problem is somewhere else. Maybe your use-case shouldn't allow to call it multiple times, maybe you should cleanup old data before using the newly received one, etc. Perhaps if you have explained in details what kind of problems you face we could help more. But as far as the `CompositeSubscription` is concerned - you're using it and unsubscribing from it correctly!

Comment: but `onDestroy` is not guaranteed to be called. Does it mean that if the `onDestroy` is not called called for some reason there would be memory leak because `unsubscribe` is not called in this case either?

Comment: Since your `Observable` only emits one item, why not use a `Single` instead? Instead of `onNext()`, it calls a `SingleSubscriber`'s `onSuccess()` once, and then it's done (there is no `onComplete()` call).

Answer (score 29):

There is no need to unsubscribe in `onCompleted`. Take a look at [The Observable Contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html)

> When an Observable issues an OnError or OnComplete notification to its
>   observers, this ends the subscription. Observers do not need to issue
>   an Unsubscribe notification to end subscriptions that are ended by the
>   Observable in this way.

On the other hand, you definitely should unsubscribe in `onDestroy` in order to prevent memory leaks.

Answer (score 5):

I think that depends on your needs. If the activity won't wait for any other calls, I suppose you could unsubscribe inside onCompleted().

I always unsubscribe in onDestroy()

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (subscription != null) {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

EDIT: take a look at http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subscriptions/CompositeSubscription.html

```
private CompositeSubscription mCompositeSubscription = new CompositeSubscription();

private void doSomething() {
    mCompositeSubscription.add(
        AndroidObservable.bindActivity(this, Observable.just("Hello, World!"))
       .subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s)));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mCompositeSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: With example 2 you have to declare as many subscriptions (member variables) as ones you use in activity and in on Destroy unsubscribe them all, right?

Comment: In my project I am using CompositeSubscription, and inside the test method  I add the subscription to CompositeSubscription. The problem I've found (and thats the reason of the post) is about calling test method several times. Doing so I realized we have n subscription (the same) added to CompositeSubscription list.

Comment: @MarcForn sorry, I do not understand.. do you want to edit the post and explain the test problem? maybe I can help

Comment: Yes, edited: The problem appears when I call several times the test method, for instance is called in a "pull to refresh". So doing that the CompositeSubscription is getting increased over and over. How would you unsubscribe that properly?