# Android RxJava wrong return type for subscription

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I just started out with RxJava and RxAndroid and was working through [this basic example](https://www.toptal.com/android/functional-reactive-android-rxjava). I'm having trouble with the last part where I subscribe to the observable which is this code.

```
subscription = GithubClient.getInstance()
            .getStarredRepositories(userName)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<GithubRepo>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<GithubRepo> githubRepos) {
                    githubRepoAdapter.setGithubRepos(githubRepos);
                }
            });
```

I don't know if the tutorial is outdated or if I'm doing something wrong. I thought it might me because my imports are wrong but I've tried them all and none work. These are the imports for this code.

```
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import rx.Observer;
import rx.Subscription;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;
```

I've also tried these:

```
import io.reactivex.Observer;
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;
import rx.Subscription;
```

But then the observer must implement different methods:

```
    subscription = GithubClient.getInstance()
            .getStarredRepositories(userName)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<GithubRepo>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<GithubRepo> githubRepos) {
                    githubRepoAdapter.setGithubRepos(githubRepos);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
```

With this code I get the error `Required: rx.Subscription, Found: void`

Relevant dependencies:

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.6'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.5.0'
```

Comment: what is the problem in the first code example?

Comment: Then I get the error "cannot resolve method subscribe(anonymous rx.Observer...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to example on your link RxJava-1 is used. But in your imports RxJava-2 is imported =)

In the 2nd RX subscribe method was changed, now it returns void.

Try to use subscribeWith() instead of subscribe(), or call subscribe() as a void function

Comment: Okay thanks! subscribeWith() returns an observer so that also doesn't work. What exactly do you mean with calling subscribe() as a void function? I'm a complete beginner with RxJava. Also, which ones are the right imports? Thanks!

Comment: I ment that you might just call 
`GithubClient.getInstance().....subscribe()`
not
`subscription = GithubClient.getInstance().....subscribe()`

The result of rx operation will be the same.
The only thing why you need `subscription` is to unsubscribe later,

Comment: For example you start long running operation on subscribe at Activity, but few moments later user leaves activity. In this case subscription allows you to unsubscribe and save resources.

rx is a complex topic. take a look at these links

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756858/when-to-unsubscribe-a-subscription)

[link](https://medium.com/engineering-brainly/how-to-leak-memory-with-subscriptions-in-rxjava-ae0ef01ad361)

[link](https://lorentzos.com/you-should-unsubscribe-onpause-51b3db60ce48)

Answer (score -1):

Check [this](https://github.com/yaroslav-android/FetchPublicGitHubRepos) one. It is a working project, but a bit complex. You do not need to use the second request, just use the first one.

```
val allRepositories =
    gitHubApi.getAllPublicRepositories().map {
    // taken sublist because GitHub has a restriction up to 60 calls rate limit per hour.
    it.subList(0, 5)
    }.doOnError {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: ", it)
    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

and do other modifications as you want.

> GitHub has a restriction up to 60 calls rate limit per hour.

Maybe you should check it https://api.github.com/rate_limit